# Is there a stainless steel thermal carafe that will fit a Bunn BTX-BT brewer other than the one that comes with it?

Tags: equipment, coffee-machines

The carafe that comes with this brewer is not designed well. Coffee splatters in all directions while pouring, especially towards the end of the pot. I like the brewer so I am looking for a different carafe to use with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this exact brewer. This may seem counterintuitive, but I would suggest removing the lid from the carafe before pouring. The lid has a narrow rectangular notch through which the coffee passes during pour, and it is the shape of the notch that causes the splash.

Bunn has actually had a couple of versions of the BTX-BT carafe, and the current design is focused on maximum thermal retention. Unfortunately, the trade-off is difficult pour control.